# Can I initialize integers in an array if the size of it is not given in advance in C?

Tags: c

I have a simple question. We know that we can set a particular  limit to a string and initialize any words in it as long as the words does not exceed the limit of the string array.As an example:

```
  str[100]="HELLO WORLD";
```

Here I didnt have to put 100characters.But can i do the same with an array of integers by using for loop and avoid garbage values?Like:

```
4-array size
2 2 3-given value
```

here i just want to assign some integer values to an array and the rest of the indices that are left unasiggned will be automatically assigned to 0. Then even if i the user does not give me the array size i can put the other indices to 0. As an example:

```
  n=5.

  number[5];

  for(i=0;i<n;i++)

 {

  scanf(“%d”,&number[i]);

//suppose user only assigned three integers which is 
 //number[0],number[1],number[2]

  // the rest of the array number[3],number[4] are garbage values which i 
  //want to turn them to 0’s.how?
 }
```

Comment: You mean something like `int arr[10] = { 1, 2,3}`?

Comment: @klutt yes but by using a for loop

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do. Yes, you can assign values to an array in a loop.

Comment: Not unless you mean something like `/* unsigned */ int data[100] = {2, 2, 3, -1};` and treat the `-1` as *end of data* (similar as how `'\0'` is treated as *end of string*)

Comment: @nevermind Both your statements are false for C and true for C++

Comment: @nevermind the question is tagged C, so `std::vector` is n ot an option.

Comment: Yes I dont know the size of array,like in strings i can set any size for it.But i cant do the same with array.

Comment: I don't understand the concept behind `4 -- 2, 2, 3`.

Comment: @RohanBari it means that i set the limit of the array size to 4.but they assigned  only 3 integers which is 2 2 3.it means i dont know how many integers will they will assign to the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use variable length arrays. However, such arrays cannot be initialized, so you have to zero them manually if you want to avoid garbage values.

```
int n = 5;
int arr[n];
memset(arr, 0, sizeof arr);
```

Or use dynamic allocation:

```
int n = 5;
int *arr = calloc(n, sizeof *arr);
```

Comment: is dynamic allocation similar to loop,like can i assign any integers that i want?also will the compiler show me the output(without garbage values) even if i assign 3 integers instead of 5?

Comment: The above code snippets will create an array of size `n` and set all values to zero. After that you can do whatever you want with them.

Comment: can you show me a simple array using dynamic allocation in C?

Comment: I honestly cannot understand what's unclear. The second snippet shows precisely that. If you want help, you need to be more specific.

Comment: your help was enough i will figure out the later by myself thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.

The following demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  // char array of size 6 initialized with A,B and C in the first 3 elements
  char str[6] = "ABC";
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    printf("str[%d] = %d\n", i, str[i]);
  }

  // int array of size 6 initialized with 1, 2 and 3 in the first 3 elements    
  int array[6] = {1,2,3};
  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
  {
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
str[0] = 65
str[1] = 66
str[2] = 67
str[3] = 0
str[4] = 0
str[5] = 0
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 2
array[2] = 3
array[3] = 0
array[4] = 0
array[5] = 0
```

All elements that have not been initialized have a default value of 0.

Comment: you already assigned three integers in the array.But i have to assign the integer using scanf inside a loop.so as long as i dont assign 6 integers the compiler will not show me the output.

Comment: @AfifAl'Hasnain you never mentioned scanf in your question. It's pretty unclear what you're asking. Maybe you want this: `int array[6] = {0};`: this initializes all 6 values of the array to 0. Or more precisely: it initializes the first element to 0 and it initializes all other elements to the default initialisation value which is always zero. Then you use scanf or what ever to put values into the array.